# How to determine the limit points of $a_{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{(1+\frac{i}{k})}$ with $i^2=-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Given a complex sequence $$a_{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{(1+\frac{i}{k})}$$ with $i^2=-1$, prove that all the limit points of $a_n$ consist of a circle in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $(b_n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{k^2})}}$ obtained from taking modulus of $(a_n)$,

Any convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ of $(a_n)$ has limit point on a circle with radius as limit of $(b_{n_k})$.

Since $(b_n)$ converges, any subsequence $(b_{n_k})$ must converges to a fixed number. Hence any limit point must have modulus as the limit of $(b_n)$, i.e. on same circle.

by (28) of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html ,

the radius of that circle is $\sqrt{\dfrac{sinh(\pi)}{\pi}}$.

Comment: Can you give a more elementary method to calculate the limit of $b_n$. @L KM

Comment: I think you haven’t prove that for every point $c$ in that circle, there is a subsequence of it that converges to $c$.@L KM

Comment: Just take argument on the sequence to form a new sequence $(c_n)=(\sum arctan(\dfrac{1}{n}))$, its sum series does not converges, by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314945/why-does-arctan1-n-summed-not-converge . For any point $x$ on the limit circle, let $y=arg(x)$. Hence it suffices to find a subsequence of $(c_n)$ that converges to y modulo $2 \pi$.

Comment: Let $(d_n)=(arctan(1/n))$. A not-so-rigorous construction of subsequence of $(c_n)$ is as below: Firstly, add suitable number of terms from $(d_n)$ (say $arctan(1)+...+arctan(1/n)$) such that their sum are just 'behind' $2 \pi +y$ (differ strictly by at most $arctan(1/(n+1))$. Suppose our subsequence is constructed up to $k$ th term, to construct $c_{n_{k+1}}$, we add suitable number of terms from $(d_n)$ such that $c_{n_{k+1}}$ differ strictly from $2(k+1)\pi +y$ by at most $arctan(1/(n_{k+1}+1)$. Since the sequence $(d_n)$ converges to $0$, hence it must converges to $y$ modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: For an elementary method to evaluate limit $(b_n)$, since it involve $sinh, \pi$, any method I can think of is not elementary.